# How to send notifications when my app is not running?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am writing an Android app. I want to send notifications to a device which is not currently running my app. I want to notify what all the new features my app will provide, or when i text something to a person he should be notified about that. How this can be done??

Can we do it with parse.com? If not then what?
Thanx in advance

Comment: Use a remote database. I.e.: parse.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use Parse Push Notifications for sending messages to devices directly. Another option available would be Google Cloud Messaging. Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)..

But for all cloud messaging services, you will have to provide a background service which can receive this message and handle it as per requirement. Means, a service will be running in background even when the app is not running in foreground.